# Possible CSS/Jquery Style Issue on Datepicker

Tags: jquery, css

I have a weird issue maybe someone can help me figure out why my datepicker calendar for jquery is not working

[image: Jquery Datepicker]

So the datepickers current day padding seems to be constrained 
Does anyone know what id or class jquery ui css uses to style that with more padding or something?

Comment: Inspect the element using F12 on your browser.

Comment: That's *very* easy to discover with Chrome's Developer Tools or Firebug for Firefox.

Comment: Chances are, it's something you did to a `td a` style in your css. Make sure to include a parent when CSSing table elements. Like `id` your table and CSS it by id of table or a wrapper div with a class name, or something.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably something related to a CSS style you made on `td a` without using a parent. This is why it's important to use a wrapper class when styling many children, like table cells. For example:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .my-table td a { padding: .1em; }
</style>

<table class="my-table">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="bob.htm">BOB</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then again, looking it over, it might be a style edit you made to `ui-state-highlight`. If so, just change your line to something like `div:not(.ui-datepicker) .ui-state-highlight`.

As for jQueryUI's class name calls for datepicker:

- `a`: anchor for today is:

  - `.ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight`
  - `.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active`
  - `.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default`
  - `.ui-datepicker td span, .ui-datepicker td a`
- td: for table cell of today:

  - `.ui-datepicker td`